# XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent manipulation from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, c, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm struggling with this issue: I have a web interface that connects, using sockets, to various C programs running on some routerboards. Every time the C application sends something through the socket, the PHP application receives it.
Everything works perfectly for one-shot requests, but there is one case where I need to update the interface on the browser each time the C application sends an update, up until it ends its task. I can successfully start the process by using a jQuery.ajax call to the PHP script that handles the communication with the C application, and I've managed to send an `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` back to the client after each update by writing something to the PHP output buffer and flushing it every time the script receives something through the socket it has open towards the C application. Thing is, I'd like to add some meaningful data to the `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent`, and I can see by inspecting it that it has both a `target` and a `srcTarget` properties that are `XMLHttpRequest`s. I thought that the `responseText` for one of those would be the content of the buffer, but it's not.

So my question is: How can I encapsulate data inside an `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` from PHP , and is there a better way than using flush to send that event?

Some code:

**C**

```
pipe = popen(command, "r");

while(!feof(pipe)) {
if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    tcp_send(currentHandler, buffer);
}

pclose(pipe);
```

(Yes, I actually execute another process and I send back the output, at least for now).

**PHP**

```
$done = false;

while(!$done) {
$buffer = socket_read($socket, 128);

if (!$buffer || $buffer == "")
    $done = true;

        // I'd like to send back the value of $buffer as well!

    echo ".";
    flush();
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myScript.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {action: 'runTest', ajax: true},
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('Aye!');
    },
    progress: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('Nay!');
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

(Of course I extended the jQuery.ajax to handle the progress event)

**UPDATE** According to the W3C [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/) a progress event can only have the `lengthComputable`, `total` and `loaded` values. Fair enough. I'd still like to be able to set their respective values :)

Answer (score -1):

Try Node.js Maybe it can be useful for you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the amount of code it would take to rewrite all the server code in Node.js is just not worth it.